# How can I fix: Cannot save the credit memo?

Tags: creditmemo, order-duplication

I am trying to create a credit memo in my store but I keep getting this error

`Cannot save the credit memo`

I have checked the exception.log and can see the following:

`Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100003910' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_CREDITMEMO_INCREMENT_ID`

I wanted to ask if I should change the value in the database to the next increment or is there a better way to solve this problem?

I'd be greatful for any advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the following tables using the offending increment id: eav_entity_store
sales_flat_creditmemo

After a bit of investigation you will find that there is a credit memo that conflicts for the last_increment_id stored in eav_entity_store for the store you are attempting to credit via or no last_increment_id record for credit memos in the eav_entity_store.

The correct fix is to adjust the eav_entity_store changing the last_increment_id for the store where the entity_type_id is 7 (7 is credit memo on my instance, if unsure review magento matching the increment id's).

Comment: On mine there is no credit memo for it (it was order 600000001, made 600000001 and shipment 600000001 but no credit memo so no credit memo line).

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is okay to answer your own question once in a while...

Inside the  `sales_flat_creditmemo` table look for `increment_id` column and change the number to one increment above the current number. For example, the increment_id was `100003910` so I changed it to `100003911` and I can now create credit memos.

**UPDATE**
Another even better approach would be to use the Fooman Order Number Customiser. I've added to help with the duplication of Order No. Shipment No. Invoice No. and Credit Memo across mulitple stores...

Comment: it mean i got error in 200000001 this number so, i should changes it with 200000002. right?

Comment: @Michel06 Yea that should solve it

Comment: okey thanks and shipping also not working what to do for it? same step? same error in ship too.

Comment: @Michel06 Yes, please try the same step for shopping. Let us know if it works...

Comment: Okey. but i am afraid to change creditmemo number frm database its live and old site. if it may harm with existing same number credit memo then? "(

Comment: do you know how to set increment id while creditmemo save? then i want to use like when new creditmemo generate i will set changed incremented id so in database it save with new number so old record can be safe.

Comment: i have done it little different way. it may be harmful but Done for me :)

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: Try this only in Test Order it may delete your order number from sales > order Grid**

in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Abstract.php this file

```
protected function _beforeSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
    {
        if ($this->_useIncrementId && !$object->getIncrementId()) {
            /* @var $entityType Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type */
            $entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode($this->_entityTypeForIncrementId);
            $object->setIncrementId($entityType->fetchNewIncrementId($object->getStoreId()));
        }
        parent::_beforeSave($object);
        return $this;
    }
```

from above code. Put below two lines outside IF condition and then try to generate credit memo it will works.

```
     $entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode($this->_entityTypeForIncrementId);
     $object->setIncrementId($entityType->fetchNewIncrementId($object->getStoreId()));
```

then reward changes.

***Keep in Mind this is needed only for one record; Next onward it will start working***